# What Makefile rule is appending .c to a missing include?

Tags: gcc, makefile, gnu-make

In a makefile, there is a statement:

`include $(PROJECT_CUSTOM_DIR)/project_custom.mak`

In some cases, this file will not exist. In those cases, we get the error saying "no such file or directory". However, it appears that an implicit rule (or something), appends the extension `.c` which then matches one of our standard rules for compiling `.c` to `.o` files, and it tries to compile it.

Our default rule for `.c` files looks like this:

```
PROJECT_CUSTOM_DIR   := .

include $(PROJECT_CUSTOM_DIR)/project_custom.mak

C_EXT             ?= c
CXX_EXT           ?= cpp
OBJ_EXT           ?= o

%.$(OBJ_EXT)        :   $(C_SRCS)
    $(COMPILE_C_COMMAND)
```

The error from the log is here:

```
Makefile:10: project_custom.mak: No such file or directory
gcc -c -fvisibility=hidden -O3 -flto -mtune=generic project_custom.mak.c -o project_custom.mak.o
```

I've read quite a lot trying to determine what is happening here and am stumped.  Can anyone explain this behavior?

Also, I am aware of that adding a dash such as `-include file.mak` suppresses the error about the file not being found. Also, disabling implicit rules is not an option here.

Thanks!

Comment: How is $(C_SRCS) made?

Comment: It is created in a separate script before make is run, in a separate .mak file. It is included before the file with the rule. I will take a closer look at the order of includes in2 hours.

Comment: `$(C_SRSC)` is not your problem.  The fact that something is trying to build `project_custom.mak.o` is.   You may want to run `make --debug=b` to see why that is trying to be built.   Your bug is outside the scope of what you posted.

Comment: [using implicit rules](https://ftp.gnu.org/old-gnu/Manuals/make-3.79.1/html_chapter/make_10.html) says that if you mention foo.o but do not give a rule for it, make will automatically look for an implicit rule that tells how to update it.  This happens whether or not the file foo.o currently exists.  So if `$(C_SRCS)` contains `project_custom.mak.c`, then make will use the c compiler gcc to build it.  I would print debug info with `echo $(C_SRCS)`

Answer (score 0):

Based on comments, I've now run make with debugging. I found that Make is doing normal/expected evaluation of all files that are included with `include(file)`. The implicit rules for included files is to try to rebuild them if they do not exist. Since this is not what I wanted, I used the following empty explicit rule to override the behavior, and do nothing for all my included files.  This was easy in my case because they all share the `.mak` extension.  Here is the rule:

`%.mak  : ;`

Thanks to those who added feedback.